# Generating ordered sequences using small sequences in python (NP hard)

Tags: python, python-2.7, sequences, np

I have a problem. I think it is an NP hard problem but I am not sure of it. First, let me describe the space;

Assume that I have the events `a,b,c,d,e,f` then, consider all possibilities of 3-length ordered sequences generated from these events. Like,

```
list1: ['a','b','c']
list2: ['a','b','d']
list3: ['a','b','e']
....
....
list120: ....
```

Order is important for the sequences so there will be total 120 3-length sequences (permutation of 6 events). Moreover, all of these 3-length sequences will be its own value between 0 and 1.

Now consider a 6-length sequence.

```
seq = ['a','b','c','d','e','f']
```

Value of `seq` can be determined as summing up all 3-length sequences in `seq`.

All 3-length sequences from `seq` can be found by taking any 3 events from `seq` without changing its order. Some examples of them;

```
seq1: ['a','b','c']
seq2: ['a','b','d']
seq3: ['a','b','e']
seq4: ['a','b','f']
....
....
seq20: ['d','e','f']
```

The question is;

I need to find a *6-length sequence* which has smallest (or largest) value among all possible 6-length sequences. As you can guess, this is just a simple example. I need to work on largest spaces having 20-100 events. Hence generating all 6-length sequences space is not a solution.

I know it is real hard to find smallest (or largest), so it may be also acceptable to find a sequence whose value is close to smallest (or largest). I would appreciate it if you can suggest an algorithm or a way which I can implement on Python.

Thanks,

Comment: What do you mean by largest (or smallest) value?

Comment: Every 6 length sequence has its own value and I need to find a sequence which has largest (or smallest) value.